# Managing multiple collisions in a single frame

Tags: collision-detection

I have a object with box collider that spins 360 degrees before destroying itself. I have a lot of enemies spawning around the player. The object spawns, spins and destroys itself. Imagine it like scythe. But only some enemies are getting damaged and some are not. The code is given below:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    damage(collision.gameObject);
}

void damage(GameObject other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemies"))
    {
        // Damaging the enemy
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<Health_Enemy>().health -= Damage;
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<Health_Enemy>().check();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do all enemies have the `Enemies` tag? Have you noticed any pattern on which enemies are damaged and which are not? Is it possible that the enemies that are damaged push other enemies away so they are outside the damage range? Does the spinning object (scythe?) rotate very fast, making it skip a few enemies maybe ?

Comment: Rotation is tricky because a long skinny object might sweep out a large wedge over the course of a rotation, even if its starting and ending poses don't intersect any of the hits in that wedge. [You may need to use a swept collision check as I describe in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/207686/39518) to catch objects skipped over in between.